# Reverse Sorted Dictionary in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, iteration, reverse

Is there any way I can iterate backwards (in reverse) through a SortedDictionary in c#?

Or is there a way to define the SortedDictionary in descending order to begin with?

Comment: Typo...Thanks for all the human compilers :-)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The SortedDictionary itself doesn't support backward iteration, but you have several possibilities to achieve the same effect.

1. Use `.Reverse`-Method (Linq). (This will have to pre-compute the whole dictionary output but is the simplest solution)

   ```
   var Rand = new Random();

   var Dict = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();

   for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
       var newItem = Rand.Next(1, 100);
       Dict.Add(newItem, (newItem * newItem).ToString());
   }

   foreach (var x in Dict.Reverse()) {
       Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", x.Key, x.Value);
   }
   ```
2. Make the dictionary sort in descending order.

   ```
   class DescendingComparer<T> : IComparer<T> where T : IComparable<T> {
       public int Compare(T x, T y) {
           return y.CompareTo(x);
       }
   }

   // ...

   var Dict = new SortedDictionary<int, string>(new DescendingComparer<int>());
   ```
3. Use `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` instead. The performance is not as good as the dictionary's (O(n) instead of O(logn)), but you have random-access at the elements like in arrays. When you use the generic IDictionary-Interface, you won't have to change the rest of your code.

Edit :: Iterating on SortedLists

You just access the elements by index!

```
var Rand = new Random();


var Dict = new SortedList<int, string>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
    var newItem = Rand.Next(1, 100);
    Dict.Add(newItem, (newItem * newItem).ToString());
}

// Reverse for loop (forr + tab)
for (int i = Dict.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", Dict.Keys[i], Dict.Values[i]);
}
```

Comment: [This library](https://github.com/madelson/MedallionComparers#reverse) defines a `Reverse()` extension method on `IComparer<T>` which makes the comparer approach even more concise.

Answer (score 21):

The easiest way to define the SortedDictionary in the reverse order to start with is to provide it with an `IComparer<TKey>` which sorts in the reverse order to normal.

Here's some code from [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) which might make that easier for you:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MiscUtil.Collections
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Implementation of IComparer{T} based on another one;
    /// this simply reverses the original comparison.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    public sealed class ReverseComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
    {
        readonly IComparer<T> originalComparer;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the original comparer; this can be useful
        /// to avoid multiple reversals.
        /// </summary>
        public IComparer<T> OriginalComparer
        {
            get { return originalComparer; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new reversing comparer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="original">The original comparer to 
        /// use for comparisons.</param>
        public ReverseComparer(IComparer<T> original)
        {
            if (original == null)
            { 
                throw new ArgumentNullException("original");
            }
            this.originalComparer = original;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the result of comparing the specified
        /// values using the original
        /// comparer, but reversing the order of comparison.
        /// </summary>
        public int Compare(T x, T y)
        {
            return originalComparer.Compare(y, x);
        }
    }
}
```

You'd then use:

```
var dict = new SortedDictionary<string, int>
     (new ReverseComparer<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCulture));
```

(or whatever type you were using).

If you only ever want to iterate in one direction, this will be more efficient than reversing the ordering afterwards.

Comment: It would be quite useful to provide a framework-integrated casting method from Comparison<T> to Comparer<T> since the delegate is much easier to handle (lambda method) ;-)

Comment: I've got a class in MiscUtil for that as well :)

Comment: Nice ;-) Should be part of the framework anyway. There is even such a class internally but it's held private ;-)

Comment: @Dario Absolutely. This "omission" in the framework was corrected in 2012 (.NET 4.5) when the [method `Comparer<>.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh737198.aspx) was introduced which takes in a `Comparison<>` delegate and returns a corresponding `IComparer<>` (in fact it returns a `Comparer<>` which implements both `IComparer<>` and `IComparer`).

Answer (score 14):

Briefly create a reversed sorted dictionary **in one line**.

```
var dict = new SortedDictionary<int, int>(Comparer<int>.Create((x, y) => y.CompareTo(x)));
```

There's a way to create a `IComparer<T>` using `System.Collections.Generic.Comparer<T>`. Just pass a `IComparision<T>` delegate to its `Create` method to build a `IComparer<T>`.

```
var dict = new SortedDictionary<int, TValue>(
    Comparer<int>.Create(
        delegate(int x, int y)
        {
            return y.CompareTo(x);
        }
    )
);
```

You can use a **lambda expression**/**local function**/**method** to replace the delegate if their significance are `(TKey, TKey) => int`.

Answer (score 10):

There is also a very simple approach if you are dealing with numeric values as the key which is to simply negate them when you create the dictionary.

Comment: That's actually a very nice approach.

Answer (score -2):

If you're using .NET 3.5, you can use the OrderByDescending extension method:

```
        var dictionary = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();
        dictionary.Add(1, "One");
        dictionary.Add(3, "Three");
        dictionary.Add(2, "Two");
        dictionary.Add(4, "Four");



        var q = dictionary.OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Key);
        foreach (var item in q)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " , " + item.Value);
        }
```

Comment: That's bad!! OrderByDescending needs O(nlogn) time to sort data which have already been sorted!