# C# .NET: Descending comparison of a SortedDictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, comparable

I'm want a `IDictionary<float, foo>` that returns the larges values of the key first.

```
private IDictionary<float, foo> layers = new SortedDictionary<float, foo>(new DescendingComparer<float>());

class DescendingComparer<T> : IComparer<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        return -y.CompareTo(x);
    }
}
```

However, this returns values in order of the smallest first. I feel like I'm making a stupid mistake here.

Just to see what would happen, I removed the `-` sign from the comparator:

```
    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        return y.CompareTo(x);
    }
```

But I got the same result. This reinforces my intuition that I'm making a stupid error.

This is the code that accesses the dictionary:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<float, foo> kv in sortedLayers)
{
    // ...
}
```

**UPDATE:** This works, but is too slow to call as frequently as I need to call this method:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<float, foo>> sortedLayers = layers.OrderByDescending(kv => kv.Key);
foreach (KeyValuePair<float, ICollection<IGameObjectController>> kv in sortedLayers) { 
    // ...
}
```

**UPDATE:** I put a break point in the comparator that never gets hit as I add and remove kv pairs from the dictionary. What could this mean?

Comment: I think you are confusing ascending with descending. Ascending is 1 2 3 4 5 (smallest value first), descending is 5 4 3 2 1 (largest value first).

Comment: `y.CompareTo(x)` should work for descending order. Why would it not? :o If you give few samples and output it will be easier to know. See [reverse-sorted-dictionary-in-net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931891/reverse-sorted-dictionary-in-net)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For descending order (largest values first), you would do `-x.CompareTo(y)`

Comment: @Rosarch: It definitely should work, I know I've used it before.  If you debug your code, do you find that your Compare method is actually called?

Comment: Looks like it isn't, actually. Am I creating the `SortedDictionary` incorrectly?

Comment: @Rosarch: No, you are creating the dictionary correctly.  Check to make sure that you are using the same dictionary you've constructed above later on in your code when adding/removing elements and enumerating.  IE. Find all references to `layers` and make sure there isn't another piece of code assigning a different `SortedDictionary`.

Comment: Negating can be a bad idea. If the `int` is the most negative value possible, `-2147483648`, then the negation of that is the same number, `-2147483648`. So it is better to swap `x` and `y`, as in `y.CompareTo(x)`, than to prepend a minus, as `-x.CompareTo(y)`. If you do not know if one of the comparands is `null`, you can use `Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(y, x)`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
public int Compare(T x, T y)
{
    return x.CompareTo(y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line, switch x and y:

```
return -y.CompareTo(x);
```

Make it

```
return -x.CompareTo(y);
```