# Reversed Sorted Dictionary?

Tags: c#

I have a `SortedDictionary` as defined like this:

```
SortedDictionary<TPriority, Queue<TValue>> dict;
```

But I want to maintain the dict in reverse order. I assume I need set the `Comparer`, but what comparer do I use for a generic `TPriority`? Note that `TPriority` implements `IComparable`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse Sorted Dictionary in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931891/reverse-sorted-dictionary-in-net)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a reverse comparer quite easily:

```
public sealed class ReverseComparer<T> : IComparer<T> {
    private readonly IComparer<T> inner;
    public ReverseComparer() : this(null) { }
    public ReverseComparer(IComparer<T> inner) {
        this.inner = inner ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
    }
    int IComparer<T>.Compare(T x, T y) { return inner.Compare(y, x); }
}
```

Now pass that into the constructor for the dictionary:

```
var dict = new SortedDictionary<TPriority, Queue<TValue>>(
                 new ReverseComparer<TPriority>());
```

Comment: Why pass `null` and then check for it, when you could have passed in `Comparer<T>.Default` in the first place?

Comment: Tasty use of `sealed`, `readonly` and the null-coalescing operator.

Comment: @Mark - well, I could have, but then I really should have added a `NullArgumentException` check a well, etc.

Comment: Ohh... in case they explicitly pass a null object to the c'tor. That makes sense then.

Comment: Nice.  is there any advantage/disadvantage to having two constructors (one which calls the other) as listed here vs simply having one constructor which takes an optional parameter (with default value null)?

Comment: @Adam only that not everyone has C# 4.0 ;p

Comment: @Mark Ah!  I actually work in vb.net not C# and wasn't aware the optioanl parameters were not possible in 3.5 in C#

Answer (score 1):

If you can use LINQ, you can just do:

```
dict.Keys.Reverse();
```

This yields the keys of the collection in reverse order.

EDIT: The `SortedDictionary` class is assigned a `IComparer<T>` when it is constructed, and this cannot be changed after the fact. However, you can create a new `SortedDictionary<T>` from the original:

```
class ReverseComparer<T> : IComparer<T>  {
   private readonly m_InnerComparer = new Comparer<T>.Default;

   public ReverseComparer( IComparer<T> inner )   {
      m_InnerComparer = inner; }

   public int Compare( T first, T second )  {
       return -m_InnerComparer.Compare( first, second );  }
}

var reverseDict = new SortedDictionary<TPriority, Queue<TValue>>( dict, 
                          new ReverseComparer( Comparer<TPriority>.Default ) );
```

Comment: Well, I didn't mean that I wanted the keys in reverse order, I meant that I want to maintain the dict in reverse order so that when I iterate over it, it will always be in descending order...

Comment: @Mark:Perhaps then you should not have said that you wanted the keys in reverse order.  You should edit your question to make sure it is clear for the benefit of those who search in the future.

Comment: @Tom: I didn't say that I "wanted the keys in the reverse order". I said I wanted to sort the keys in reverse order, thereby sorting the dict. I said "keys" to distinguish from sorting the queues/TValues, but I understand where the confusion came from. Amended.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just adding this to my class, as it's the shortest and simplest:

```
private class ReverseComparer : IComparer<TPriority>
{
    public int Compare(TPriority x, TPriority y) { return y.CompareTo(x); }
}
```

And then initialize the `dict` like so:

```
dict = new SortedDictionary<TPriority, Queue<TValue>>(new ReverseComparer());
```