# How do I get previous key from SortedDictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorteddictionary

I have dictionary containing key value pairs.

```
SortedDictionary<int,int> dictionary=new SortedDictionary<int,int>();
dictionary.Add(1,33);
dictionary.Add(2,20);
dictionary.Add(4,35);
```

I want to get previous key value pair from a known key value. In the above case, if I have key 4, then how can I get `<2,20>`?

Comment: SortedDictionary<int,int> dictionary=new SortedDictionary<int,int>();

Comment: I think the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931891/sorted-dictionary-in-c) explain how to do what you want.

Comment: Is there any Linq query which will give me previous key.

Comment: user578083, I have given an answer below using linq query check it out... ok :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's hard to implement this efficiently with a `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` since it is implemented as a binary search tree that does not expose predecessors or successors.

You could of course just enumerate each KeyValuePair until you find the "known" key. With a little bit of LINQ, this would look like (assuming the key definitely exists and isn't the first key):

```
SortedDictionary<int, int> dictionary = ...
int knownKey = ...

var previousKvp = dictionary.TakeWhile(kvp => kvp.Key != knownKey)
                            .Last();
```

If those assumptions don't hold, you could do:

```
var maybePreviousKvp = dictionary.TakeWhile(kvp => kvp.Key != knownKey)
                                 .Cast<KeyValuePair<int, int>?>()
                                 .LastOrDefault();
```

(Check that `maybePreviousKvp != null` to ascertain that the previous KeyValuePair was retrieved successfully.)

But this isn't going to be efficient at all.

---

If feasible, consider using a [**`SortedList<TKey, TValue>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) instead (obviously, this may not be possible if you can't take its slower inserts and deletes). This collection supports efficient key and value-retrieval by *ordered* index since it is implemented as a growable array. Then your query becomes as simple as:

```
SortedList<int, int> dictionary = ...
int knownKey = ...

int indexOfPrevious = dictionary.IndexOfKey(knownKey) - 1;

// if "known" key exists and isn't the first key
if(indexOfPrevious >= 0)
{
   // Wrap these in a KeyValuePair if necessary
   int previousKey = dictionary.Keys[indexOfPrevious];
   int previousValue = dictionary.Values[indexOfPrevious];      
}
```

`IndexOfKey` runs a binary search on the keys-list, running in `O(log n)` time. Everything else should run in constant time, meaning the entire operation should run in logarithmic time.

---

Otherwise, you'll have to implement yourself / find a BST collection that does expose predecessors / successors.

Answer (score 11):

I was also looking for an answer to this problem, and I thought a better solution than all of the answers here is to use the [`TreeDictionary<K, V>`](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.0/c5doc/types/C5.TreeDictionary%602.htm) from the [C5 Collections](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/index.html) ([GitHub](https://github.com/sestoft/C5/)/[NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/C5)), which is an implementation of a red-black tree.

It has `Predecessor`/`TryPredecessor` and `WeakPredessor`/`TryWeakPredecessor` methods (as well as equivalent methods for successors) which does exactly what you want.

For example:

```
TreeDictionary<int,int> dictionary = new TreeDictionary<int,int>();
dictionary.Add(1,33);
dictionary.Add(2,20);
dictionary.Add(4,35);

// applied to the dictionary itself, returns KeyValuePair<int,int>
var previousValue = dictionary.Predecessor(4);
Assert.Equals(previousValue.Key, 2);
Assert.Equals(previousValue.Value, 20);

// applied to the keys of the dictionary, returns key only
var previousKey = dictionary.Keys.Predecessor(4);
Assert.Equals(previousKey, 2);

// it is also possible to specify keys not in the dictionary
previousKey = dictionary.Keys.Predecessor(3);
Assert.Equals(previousKey, 2);
```

Comment: In case somebody doesn't know what a weak predecessor is, it's the first item **either equal to or less than** the passed value. A (strict) predecessor is the item just **less than** the passed value. Similarly for successors.

Comment: C5 collections are cool, but they have problems with the documentation for the up-to-day version, so save your time, clone the sources, and look at the source code.

Answer (score 3):

```
KeyValuePair<int, int> lookingForThis = dictionary
  .Reverse()
  .SkipWhile(kvp => kvp.Key != 4)
  .Skip(1)
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: +1. Would just like to point out that the OP's question doesn't really make sense. While this answer will return they pair before, the pair before will be continually changing as you add items to the dictionary. I think more clarification on what the OP is trying to do is needed

Comment: I think it should be `.SkipWhile(kvp => kvp.Key != 4).Skip(1)`

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the dictionary and keep track of values, I guess. Something like this:

```
public int GetPreviousKey(int currentKey, SortedDictionary<int, int> dictionary)
{
    int previousKey = int.MinValue;
    foreach(KeyValuePair<int,int> pair in dictionary)
    {
        if(pair.Key == currentKey)
        {
            if(previousKey == int.MinValue)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("There is no previous key.");
            }
            return previousKey;
        }
        else
        {
            previousKey = pair.Key;
        }
    }
}
```

However, this is a pretty odd operation to require. The fact that you need it might be pointing at a problem with your design.

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` is unsorted, so there is no *previous* thing for some item. Instead you can use [`SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx).

EDIT: Sorry I read the title only LOL.

If you *have to* use LINQ:

```
int givenKey = 4;
var previousItem = dict.Where((pair, index) => 
                                   index == dict.Count || 
                                   dict.ElementAt(index + 1).Key == givenKey)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Tried using this in a function that accepted `dict` and `givenKey` as my Dictionary and the key I was starting from, and to return `previousItem` as a string, since I have a dictionary of `<string, DateTime>`.  I get an error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, System.DateTime>' to 'string'`.  So this doesn't just return the key - I confirmed it returns the whole KeyValuePair. So in my case, I did `KeyValuePair<string, DateTime> tempKVP = MoveToPreviousKey(myDict, givenKey);` and then `string previousKey = tempKVP.Key;`. Worked great. HTH someone.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use linq if that's the case... try this it will surely work

```
SortedDictionary<int,int> dictionary = new SortedDictionary<int,int>();
dictionary.add(1, 33);
dictionary.add(2, 20);
dictionary.add(4, 35);

int SelectedKey = 4;

var ResutValue = ( from n in dictionary    
               where n.Key < TheSelectedKey
               select n.Value).Last();

this.txtResult.Text = ResultValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I havent tested it though, but should give something to start think in this direction. Hope it helps.

```
        int input = 4;
        List<int> lKeys = dictionary.Keys.ToList();
        int reqIndex = lKeys.IndexOf(input) - 1;
        int reqAnswer = dictionary[reqIndex];
```

test for other conditions like if (reqIndex != -1) etc..