# Using SortedDictionary - getting next value

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I am using SortedDictionary to store values sorted by integer.

I need to get next value after specific existing integer. I would prefer working with enumerator but there is no `GetEnumerator(Key k)` or similar function.

```
SortedDictionary<int, MyClass> _dict;


void GetNextValue(int start, out MyClass ret)
{
}
```

Comment: See: [How do I get previous previous key from SortedDictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4720674/412770). You might be better off using a `SortedList<,>`.

Comment: Why are you using a sorted dictionary for this then. Can you not use another data structure? How about a SortedList<TKey, TValue> instead?

Comment: Thanks Ani, seems that simplest way is switching to SortedList. Too bad that .NET collections do not provide consistent work with enumerators just like std libary in C++ with iterators

Comment: Shiv my task is provide collection sorted by some key with good access capabilities - move next, move previous, find value

Comment: A SortedList would allow you to do exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reference to the link that Ani added, in this case it would be something like:

```
ret = source.SkipWhile(pair => pair.Key <= start).First().Value;
```

or maybe (to allow a `Try`-style usage)

```
using(var iter = source.GetEnumerator()) {
    while(iter.MoveNext()) {
        if(iter.Current.Key > start) {
             ret = iter.Current.Value;
             return true;
        }
    }
    ret = null;
    return false;
}
```