# Can I use Linq to create a comparer for a C# sorted dictionary

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary, icomparer

Is there a way of creating a SortedDictionary using Linq? This would avoid the inconvenience (and code bloat) of creating a comparer class.

For example, create a dictionary sorted on the reverse of the string key:

```
//NOT VALID SYNTAX
SortedDictionary<string, int> sortDict = new SortedDictionary(kvp => new String(kvp.Key.Reverse().ToArray());

//VALID SYNTAX
SortedDictionary<string, int> sortDict = new SortedDictionary<string, int>(new ReverseStringComparer);

private class ReverseStringComparer: IComparer<String>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        string s1 = new string(x.Reverse().ToArray());
        string s2 = new string(y.Reverse().ToArray());
        return s1.CompareTo(s2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use Jon Skeet's [`ReverseComparer<T>`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/931941/284240) which is more efficient?

Comment: The proposed ReverseStringComparer class reverses each string and then compares them. Jon Skeet's version only inverts the sort order.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think the OP is reversing the strings before sorting, rather than sorting in reverse order.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: yes, but the `Reverse().ToArray())` is redundant since he could simple swap x and y, couldn't he?

Comment: I wouldn't try to use LINQ just for the sake of using LINQ. It's just a tool, use it when appropriate. Those few lines hardly qualify as code bloat in my opinion.

Comment: `LINQ` doesn't create comparers. But `LINQ` methods (such as OrderBy) can use Comparers.

Comment: My code actually compares the ToString() of some complex objects. The string reversal is just an example I made up for the purposes of this question (perhaps I should have made that clearer, and used a better example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a generic comparer class that applies an extraction function over the items you want to compare:

```
public class KeyComparer<TItem, TKey> : Comparer<TItem>
{
    private readonly Func<TItem, TKey> extract;
    private readonly IComparer<TKey> comparer;

    public KeyComparer(Func<TItem, TKey> extract)
        : this(extract, Comparer<TKey>.Default)
    { }

    public KeyComparer(Func<TItem, TKey> extract, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        this.extract = extract;
        this.comparer = comparer;
    }

    public override int Compare(TItem x, TItem y)
    {
        // need to handle nulls
        TKey xKey = extract(x);
        TKey yKey = extract(y);
        return comparer.Compare(xKey, yKey);
    }
}
```

I usually use this class for extracting properties; however, you could define any function, such as your string reversal:

```
SortedDictionary<string, int> sortDict = new SortedDictionary<string, int>(
    new KeyComparer<string, string>(s => new string(s.Reverse().ToArray())));
```

**Update**: I have covered this comparer in more detail in my [blog post](http://dogmamix.com/cms/blog/KeyComparer).