# How to reverse iterate the objects within the dictionary C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, dictionary

I have a similar structure as the dictionary in C# and I need to find first the required value. When the value is found, needs to get its corresponding key. Will then take that key and need to iterate backward the entire dictionary for scanning corresponding values.

Example. (`Dictionary<int, List<int>>`)

```
|0 ->1|
|1-> 2,3|
|2-> NUll|
|3-> 4,5|
|4-> 5,6,7|
|5-> 6,7|
|6-> NULL|
|7-> 8|
|8-> NULL|
```

For example, my target value is `'8'` which is found in the above dictionary at the 7th index. Now I have to backtrack until the whole dictionary is finished by surpassing the first key-value pair.

So, I want `8` as the value, its key would be `7`. From the 7th key, I should jump over back to the 5th key,( as the 7th value is present there), and from the 5th key, it should jump back to the 4th key as `5` is present in the values of `4`. From the 4th key, it should jump back to the 3rd key ( as `4` is present in the values of `3` and so on until I exhausted the dictionary traversal backward.

How can I achieve the above functionality?

Comment: When dealing with a dictionary, there's no such thing as "first" or "reverse"; they are an unordered structure.

Comment: That's why I asked, how to achieve this required functionality. As I have this entire data in the dictionary.

Comment: A plain Dictionary in C# does not have an "order". If you want the keys to be in order then you can use "OrderedDictionary" but you love the O(1) performance of a native dictionary (which you may not care about)

Comment: No. actually, these keys are indices of an array. So in this manner, these all keys are certainly in order.

Comment: _"From the 7th key, I should jump over back to the 5th key"_ - why? "7" is contained in 5 and 4. So why 5 and _not_ 4?

Comment: To to this efficiently, the canonical way would be to also create a "reverse" dictionary, i.e.,  one that maps from your "values" to your "keys". For example, `7` would map to `4,5`. That way, your algorithm just "jumps" between those two dictionaries.

Comment: The problem is not to order the keys. Problem is after getting the specific value in values, how to reverse backward finding the entire path till that value from the start of the index of an array. And here I put all array indices inside the dictionary to achieve this
for every key, there are possible indices which are placed as values

Comment: The key _values_ may have a natural order, but in a `Dictionary` they are not stored in any obvious order, so there is no concept of a "previous" value.

Comment: @Fildor : Yeah 4. My mistake. as I am in search of a path so, 4the index would be right.

Comment: Don't have time to write a full answer right now, but the last time I needed to do this, I used LINQ to get all the "pairs", e.g. (0,1), (1,2), (1,3), ... and then used `ToLookup` to converts this to the "reverse dictionary".

Comment: You'll need a recursive algorithm that, given a number, finds the highest index (less than some max position) of the item that contains that number. So you're going to have to loop through to look at the values anyway, and an `OrderedDictionary` will be best to access items by index.

Comment: Then the question would be: how to recursively look for the highest index from the existing dictionary

Comment: To me, this sounds more like a mesh-traversal. And I still don't know why one jump is preferred over another. When you have 3 -> 5 and 4 -> 5 , why would any of 3 or 4 be preferred over the other? Just because 4 > 3 ?

Comment: @Fildor : I am solving the coding problem of leetcode. https://leetcode.com/problems/jump-game/description/

Comment: Here I ended up managing a dictionary ( map ) which would have keys as indices of the array, and corresponding values would be all possible jump indices that can be approached from the current array cell value

Comment: Sorry, that link seems to lead nowhere. At least it was broken for me.

Comment: Path finding is a well studied and documented problem. Simplest solution is djikstra, but A* is typically used for better performance. But you need to transform your graph description into one you can use for efficient lookup, for example reversing the dictionary, so values map to the keys instead. Or create a large table for all graph edges.

Comment: Fildor: I don't know. But it's leetcode jump-game problem.

Comment: @JonasH: do you think it would be a breadth-first search or depth-first search problem? or something similar? In that case, I need to convert the array to graph-based data structure.

Comment: A `Dictionary` doesn't seem like the best data structure to handle this. Why don't you just iterate the input list backwards and see if, from the then-current position, the last index is reachable. Mark each entry as reachable/unreachable and then step backward. If the previous entry can reach a later entry that's already marked as reachable, the end index is reachable, otherwise it's not. At the beginning, mark the last index as reachable (since it's already the destination). Unless, of course, I misunderstand the task :)  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using the BFS(BReadth first search) technique.

I know it's not an optimized approach but somehow a solution. So idea is, try to explore all possible reachable nodes from the beginning.

```
    bool IsLastElementReachable(int[] array, int lastElementIndex, Queue<int> 
    queue, HashSet<int> visited)
    {
       var Count = array.Length;
       visited.Add(0);

       queue.Enqueue(0);

       while (queue.Count() == 0)
       {
        var start = queue.Dequeue();

        if (start == Count - 1)
            return true;

        var end = start + array[start];

        end = end >= Count ? Count - 1: end;

        for (int i = start + 1; i < end; i++)
        {
            if (i <= lastElementIndex)
            {
                if (!visited.Contains(i))
                {
                    visited.Add(i);
                    queue.Enqueue(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary entries in C# has no order to it.

Since your keys seem to be iterating in ascending order from 0 to 8, look into [SortedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=net-8.0). This sorts the elements based on its keys, since you want this to be sorted in reverse order, create the dictionary with a reverse comparer like:

```cs
var dict = new SortedDictionary<int, List<int>>(
  Comparer<int>.Create((x, y) => y.CompareTo(x))
);
```

Credits to this answer: [link to thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48622799/17985195)

That entire thread has other methods to create a reverse sorted dictionary but I am just providing the one liner which would be convenient for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

The order of `{Key, Value}` pairs is undefined in c# dictionary; assuming that we want them ordered by `Key` we can have *two dictionaries*: `direct` (having `Key` we want `Value`) and `reverse` (to obtain `Key` from `Value`), i.e. having

```
Dictionary<int, int[]> original = new() {
  { 0, new int[] { 1 } },
  { 1, new int[] { 2, 3 } },
  { 2, new int[] {} },
  { 3, new int[] { 4, 5 } },
  { 4, new int[] { 5, 6, 7 } },
  { 5, new int[] { 6, 7 } },
  { 6, new int[] {} },
  { 7, new int[] { 8 } },
  { 8, new int[] {} },
};
```

We build

```
var direct = original
  .Where(pair => pair.Value.Any())
  .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value.First());

var reverse = original
  .SelectMany(pair => pair.Value.Select(value => (key: pair.Key, value)))
  .OrderBy(item => item.key)
  .GroupBy(item => item.value, item => item.key)
  .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.First());
```

And then loop

```
IEnumerable<int> Sequence(int item) {
  for (var dict = reverse; ; dict = dict == direct ? reverse : direct) {
    yield return item;

    if (!dict.TryGetValue(item, out item))
      break;
  }
}
```

Demo:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", Sequence(7).Take(10)));
```

Output:

```
7, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h9lTyP)

Comment: Seems like a lot of unnecessary linq. Have you tested performance?

Comment: @Poul Bak: I've built `direct` and `reverse` and then use them many times in `Sequence`

Answer (score 0):

Reading the leet code problem you listed in the comments.

The problem is essentially a tree/graph search problem. But you do not need to go overboard with data structures/dictionaries. The important thing is to be able to efficiently go from one node to its children, and the original array works just fine for that:

```
var nums = new []{ 2, 3, 1, 1, 4 };

IEnumerable<int> GetNextIndices(int i)
{
    var jump = nums[i];
    var nextIndices = new List<int>();
    if(i - jump > 0) { nextIndices.Add(i - jump); }
    if (i + jump < nums.Length){nextIndices.Add(i + jump);    }
    return nextIndices;
}
```

Given a index, it will return the next 0, 1 or 2 indices to check. The major inefficiencies here is needing to create a list, you can optimize away that list, but such optimizations tend to impair readability.

The next step is to traverse the graph:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DepthFirstLoopSafe<T>(T self, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> getNextNodes)
{
    var stack = new Stack<T>();
    var visited = new HashSet<T>(EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
    stack.Push(self);
    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var current = stack.Pop();
        if (!visited.Add(current)) continue;
        yield return current;
        foreach (var node in getNextNodes(current))
        {
            stack.Push(node);
        }
    }
}
```

This is made a bit more complicated by the generic nature, but that makes it simpler to reuse for different kinds of tree structures. An important point here is to ignore already visited indices, since that could lead to an infinite loop. If you want a breadth first instead of depth first, just change the stack to a queue.

This will return a sequence of all reachable nodes, so we can just check if it contains the last index to determine if it is reachable:

```
var reachedEnd = DepthFirstLoopSafe(0, GetNextIndices).Any(i => i == nums.Length-1);
```

Comment: _"This assumes that a node has a single unique parent"_ OP's sample data suggests the opposite, though, - **if** I am not mistaken.

Comment: @fildor good point, The OP should probably clarify if it is a mistake, or if it is intended to be a graph.